# Windows 7 reactivation

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop with a bad hard drive (will not spin up) so I replaced the hard drive and reistalled windows 7 home from another OEM cd I have.  Then I ordered a new OEM cd to get a new legal product Key.  My question is, can I use the new key for activation without reinstalling windows again.

Comment: In most cases: Yes, you can change the CoA key after installation. But OEM tend to somewhat modify they DVDs and `another OEM cd` is rather vague.

Comment: Also, many (most?) OEM installs activate via a key in their firmware (E.g. BIOS or UEFI). Their DVDs ship without a CoA.

Comment: @Hennes - Your statement does not apply to Windows 7.  ALL Windows 7 licences are required to come with a COA sticker.  If there isn't a sticker then it isn't genuine in the eyes of Microsoft.

Comment: @WilliamF - Why did you get a new OEM CD if the license you had already was legal and activated?  Unless you used the license from another laptop, which shouldn't have worked, because you could have simply used the key on the sticker itself.

Comment: I used an OEM disc that has already been installed on my desktop.  I used it to install windows 7 home on the laptop prior to getting the new Oem disk I ordered. Doing this let me install windows and all the drivers for the laptop as well of all the windows updates (200 of them). Now the laptop is ready to activate as soon as I recieve the new Oem disk with a COA lable

Comment: Solved   I used a retail version not Oem when I installed on the laptop.  All is ok now and activated